# React + vite don't recognize and not load file css

Tags: reactjs, vite

I have a problem with my react-vite project.
Vite doesn't recognize my style.css file

This is my configuration file.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
})
```

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Did you import your css in your component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the final I solved with this configuration of vite :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css:{
    modules:{
      localsConvention:"camelCase",
      generateScopedName:"[local]_[hash:base64:2]"
    }

  }

})
```